# Express router not working as expected with subdirectory

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I'm dividing my api queries by modules inside a Node.js app. Therefore in the `index.js` I have:

```
app.use('/api/schedule/', apiSchedule);
```

Then, inside the apiSchedule router:

```
router.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Queried ID');
});
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Queried root');
});
router.get('/list', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Queried list');
});
router.get('/list/:id', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Queried list item');
});
```

I'm testing these routes with postman and this is the result:

```
http://localhost/api/schedule/ <-- Queried root
http://localhost/api/schedule/1 <-- Queried ID
http://localhost/api/schedule/list  <-- empty
http://localhost/api/schedule/list/ <-- empty
http://localhost/api/schedule/list/1 <-- Queried list item
```

Why querying list gives an empty response? Something wrong on my configuration or maybe the router doesn't work as I was expecting?

Notice that there is **no error response but a blank response**. Also, `console.log` inside the router functions don't get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because route path `/:id` has parameter ID so regex for this route could also accepts routes `/` and `/list` could.

Check the value of `req.params` in `/:id` route you'll see that in case `/` the ID parameter will be `undefined` and in `/list` case it will be `list`.

To fix it, you need to specify regex for `/:id`, if ID is type number then it will be something like this `/:id(\d+)`.

I had same problem with ID parameter of type UUID4 (string) so I manage to fix it using this regex `([0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-4[0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12})`